# File at a glance feature - how to enable it?

Tags: package

Sublime text has this file at a glance feature, where you see the whole file in miniature.

How can I enable this in emacs? How is this feature called?[image: file at a glance in sublime text]

Answer (score 3):

[minimap](https://github.com/dengste/minimap) looks like it is what you're after.

From the README:

> This file is an implementation of a minimap sidebar, i.e., a smaller
>   display of the current buffer on the left side. It highlights the
>   currently shown region and updates its position automatically. You can
>   navigate in the minibar by dragging the active region with the mouse,
>   which will scroll the corresponding edit buffer. Additionally, you can
>   overlay information from the tags gathered by CEDET's semantic
>   analyzer.
>
> Simply use M-x minimap-mode to toggle activation of the minimap. Use
>   'M-x customize-group RET minimap RET' to adapt minimap to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Library **[`thumb-frm.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/thumb-frm.el)** provides this and more (see [Fisheye with Thumbs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FisheyeWithThumbs)).

It lets you *"thumbify"* frames - regardless of what they're showing (a single file, multiple buffers, whatever). The result is a thumbnail size , fully functional frame (scroll-bar, whatever).

You can customize the size, and you define which frame parameters to use (e.g., menu-bar and tool-bar are removed, by default). At the touch of a key (I use `C-z`) use can thumbify and dethumbify a frame.